# Grails GSP Ajax Call OnSuccess not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I am performing an ajax call from a .gsp file in grails:

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: '<g:createLink controller="mycontroller" action="myaction"/>',
  data: params,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  onSuccess: 'toggleSaveButton(false);'
});
```

mycontroller

```
def myaction() {
    // do some funky stuff with params
    // params are available, everything here works without a problem
}
```

**outcome**

the ajax call is performed and the controller function is called correctly with all attached data.

**issue**

my `onSuccess:` is ignored and never called

**i already tried**

- using the more generic `onComplete`
- change the `onSuccess:` to `function(){toggleSaveButton(false);}`
- `render (true as JSON)` in my controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting to :

```
onComplete: dataUpdatedOnSuccess()
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `success:` instead of `onSuccess:`, according to [JQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

To demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/bL60Lta9/2/